# How to get Date of page creation on wikipedia page using python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, timestamp, wikipedia

I have a problem, with how to get a specific text in a table. In this example the date of page creation on the Wikipedia page. For example in this link

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States?action=info

I'm using beautifulsoup, but I'm still having trouble because the rest of the text is there. I just need the date of page creation only.

Comment: The rest of what text?  Exactly what text do you get?  Show us the code you used.  This is an easy one, because the `<tr>` tag has a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

Grep'ing returns a single line of HTML:

```
$ curl -s 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States?action=info' |
    grep --color 'Date of page creation'
```

In this case iterating line by line and using a regex would suffice.

But let's stick with BS4, a good tool for the job.

## 1. iterate

Just loop over the `soup.find_all('td')` tags
until you find one having `td.text`
matching "Date of page creation".
Then ask for the *next* tag,
and `td.text` has the timestamp you want.

## 2. search for tag

Take advantage of the "mw-pageinfo-firsttime" id
on the `<tr>` row, telling BS4 to look for *that*.
Read and discard a `<td>`.
Read another datum and return its `td.text` timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

there are some tables but just one table has information about the date and time. Fortunately, the row of date has a unique id that makes work easy.
so find the `tr` by the id and get its content by `.text` property or first get the second cell from this row and then get its content.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States?action=info'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

first_time = soup.find(id='mw-pageinfo-firsttime').find_all('td')[1]
last_time = soup.find(id='mw-pageinfo-lasttime').find_all('td')[1]

print(first_time.text)
print(last_time.text)
```